# Cells of CollectionView don't fit in screen

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have `CollectionView` in cell of `TableView`:
[image]

[image]

Constraints for cell in `CollectionView`

[image]

When I run app f.e. on iPhone 5s I see (cell doesn't fit at screen):
[image]

But after scroll down and up I see:
[image]

I know about reuse, but how to show cell from start as must (fit to screen)?

Comment: did this worked for you ? below answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Need to reaload your Collection View

In your TableViewCell Impleament Method

```
    func draw(_ rect: CGRect)
    {

// here you have to reaload your collectionView
        super.draw(rect)
    self.collectionView.realodData()

    }
```

refresh your TableCell By Calling its DrawRect Method

```
optional func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
            willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, 
               forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
  cell.setNeedsDisplay()
}
```

i hope this will work for you,

Comment: this doesn't worked for me can you help me please ?here is the link of my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49850234/the-collection-view-inside-table-view-cells-wont-fit-to-the-cell-even-after-con